# C Low level I/O: Bad address when reading a file

Tags: c, io, fork, low-level

I am studying low level I/O in C and multiprocess programming with fork().

In this example the parent process exchanges information about input files with the child processes.
However, reading the second input file generates the Bad address error, why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    if(argc != 4){
        printf("Numero di parametri non valido");
        exit(1);
    }

    int pipe1[2], pipe2[2];

    if(pipe(pipe1) < 0){
        perror("errore pipe");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if(pipe(pipe2) < 0){
        perror("errore pipe");
        exit(-1);
    }



    int pid;
    int pid2;

    if((pid = fork()) < 0){
        perror("errore fork");
        exit(-1);
    }






    if(pid == 0){                   //first child
        char buff[2];

        close(pipe1[0]);

        int inputF1;
        if((inputF1 = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) < 0)
            perror("errore open inputF1");

        int n;

        while((n = read(inputF1, buff, 2)) > 0){
            write(pipe1[1], buff, 2);
        }

        close(pipe1[1]);
        close(inputF1);
    }

    else{

        if((pid2 = fork()) < 0){
            perror("errore fork");
            exit(-1);
        }

        if(pid2 == 0){              //second child
            char buff2[2];

            close(pipe2[1]);

            int outputF;
            if((outputF = open(argv[3], O_RDWR | O_APPEND)) < 0)
                perror("errore open outputF");

            int n2;

            while((n2 = read(pipe2[0], buff2, 2)) > 0){
                if((write(outputF, buff2, 2)) != 2)
                    perror("errore scrittura outputF");
            }

            close(pipe2[0]);
            close(outputF);
        }

        else{                       //parent process
            char buff0[2];
            char *char_input;

            close(pipe1[1]);
            close(pipe2[0]);


            int n_padre;
            int n_input;

            int inputF2;
            if((inputF2 = open(argv[2], O_RDONLY)) < 0)
                perror("errore open inputF2");

            while((n_padre = read(pipe1[0], buff0, 2)) > 0){
                if((n_input = read(inputF2, char_input, 1)) != 1)
                    perror("errore lettura inputF2");

                if(char_input[0] != buff0[0] && char_input[0] != buff0[1])
                    write(pipe2[1], buff0, 2);
            }

            close(pipe1[0]);
            close(pipe2[1]);
            close(inputF2);
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

inputF1 content:
abcdefghi

inputF2 content:
abcd

All files are in the same directory

I run the program like this:

```
./pipe inputF1 inputF2 outputF
```

Error:

*errore lettura inputF2: Bad address*

*Segmentation fault (core dumped)*

**EDIT**

The problem was uninitialized char * char_input, thanks Mickael B.
Anyway the program now freezes and waits for something. Is there any problem with pipes?

Comment: Use `strace -f ./my_program` to trace system calls; very helpful for debugging low-level code like this.  (strace has options to log to a separate file for each process if you want)

Comment: Okay, thank you, I'll try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```c
char *char_input;
// ...
read(inputF2, char_input, 1)
```

But `char_input` is uninitialised

So you can do this

```c
char char_input[2];
```

Comment: Right, thank you very much! Anyway the program now freezes and waits for something, it only partially writes the outputF file. Is there any problem with pipes?

Comment: It freezes because you need to stop your child processes

Comment: And you should check the number of character you are reading and writing. i.e: if you read only one character maybe you don't want to write 2 characters

Comment: Right. I added checks for the number of characters and waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) and waitpid(pid2, NULL, 0) at the end but the program keeps waiting for something. 
The output on the file is correct though